# Vue 2.2.2 doesn't display the data to the View

Tags: laravel, vue.js, browserify, vueify

> Current Version : Laravel 5.2 using only Browserify not Webpack

I've already set up everything such as like this:

> In my resources/js/app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

new Vue({   el : '.row',

    data : {        name: ''    }

});
```

in my view :

```
<div class="row">
    <input type ="text">
    <h1> @{{ name }} </h1>

</div>
```

But when i try to refresh it. The DOM just renders for about 2ms or let's say split second then it's gone and there's an error that says :

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build. 
>   (found in )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `runtime-only` build but you likely need the `standalone build`, to do that simply add the following to your your `package.json` to alias the standalone build (which includes the template compiler) :

```
"browser": {
  "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
}
```

Comment: Could you add your package.json? If you're using gulp could you also add your gulpfile?

Comment: The reason might be beacuse I'm using the  the runtime-only build of Vue so  Vue won't display data for me. So i have to use components and vueify to display the data. Man, can you please share some of your js codes on me ? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'm using Vue2.2.2